# Start button in XNA and windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, xna-4.0

Writing a xna game for WP7, would like to know, during the game play if I press start button Ideally what should happen ?
1. identify start button event, code for current state save and reload on game come back  ?
2. no code, WP7 will handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP7 will handle it. Your game will freeze in it's current state. You will be able to return to that state with your back button.

Comment: is there internal process that may kill freeze app in background ?

Answer (score 1):

If by "start" button, you mean the windows/home button, then you do not implement any functionality there.  The back button is a different case and it's functionality has very specific requirements.